# What are some good JVM-based web server libraries?

Tags: java, kotlin, spark-java

I currently have a Kotlin app that I'd like to expose with a REST API server. I'm finding really hard to decide for a web framework to build around it.

My background is Node.JS with express and I'm trying to find something at least similar to it at the level of middleware and modularity. But since I just started learning Java recently the getting started part is the major entry-barrier.

What striked me as appropriate was Spark but I can't find a way to separate my routes between different files and have local-per-file middleware.

I considered Play but it seemed that it needed a very big level of setup for a new app, even more if it's an existing one.

While my app ain't that big I plan on evolving it so I need something that can scale appropriately. So I'm asking what options do I have? I'm really looking forward on working with Spark if I can tackle those 2 issues previously mentioned, any help about them is appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is likely to be closed as "to vague". What you can do is to extract "those 2 issues previously mentioned" into 2 separate questions about Spark and close this one.

Comment: You could create a github issue about separation of middleware. Pretty sure that already exists as a feature on their roadmap, though

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

- https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ (lots of libs, quiet complicated, but powerful)
- http://restx.io/
- Jersey2
- Resteasy